# Aligning numbered points on map ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to align each `bcr_code` to their respective polygons, however, the numbers come out of place. How do I get the right alignment, preferably in the middle?

here's the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

library(rgdal)

file1 <- "bcr.gpkg"
if (!file.exists(file.path("data/data/", file1))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file1),
                file.path("data/data/", file1), mode = "wb")
}

p <- readOGR(dsn = "bcr.gpkg")
tidy_bcr <- tidy(p)

ggplot(p, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", size = 0.1, fill = "lightgrey") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal()

p$id <- row.names(p)
tidy_bcr <- left_join(tidy_bcr, p@data)
bcrcop <- data.frame(bcr_name = sort(p@data$bcr_name),
                           bcr_code = c(28,17,12,24,19,22,13,26,30,21,31,29,23,11,18,27,25))
tidy_bcr <- left_join(tidy_bcr, bcrcop)

bcrLabel <- tidy_bcr %>%
  group_by(bcr_name) %>%
  summarise(label_long = mean(range(long)), label_lat = mean(range(lat)), bcr_code = mean(bcr_code))

map <- ggplot(tidy_bcr, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = bcr_name)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", size = 0.1) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 40, b = -40)))

map + geom_text(data = bcrLabel, mapping = aes(x=label_long, y = label_lat, label = bcr_code, group = NA), cex = 4, col = "white")
```

And the output:
[image]

Although, is there also a way to get these codes on the legend, something like:

```
28: Appalachian Mountains
```

Comment: No solution, but a comment: it looks like the numbers are actually ‘at the center’ — probably the center of mass. It’s just that the areas are shaped in a way that this center of mass doesn’t nicely fall into an are occupied by the shape. Where should the ‘center’ of a donut be?

Comment: @MarioNiepel Sounds like a problem with language, i.e. "what is the sound of one hand clapping". Although, common sense should show that centre represents somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Not interested, take that question to the philosophy forum. Although, here's a thought. Take the donut, and transpose it so that its seen from above at its vertical height. If you are to place a skewer through the donut, where do you find the centre? Maybe this helps towards your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `sf` package for the data and `ggsflabel` for the labels.

A minimal examle:

```r
library(sf) 
library(ggsflabel)


my_data <- read_sf('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main//bcr.gpkg') ## Replace with your path to the data

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = my_data,
          aes(fill = bcr_name)) + 
  geom_sf_label(data = my_data, aes(label = bcr_code))
```

[image]

Change the legend names in the legend using `unite` on the data first.

```
my_data <- my_data %>% 
  unite('new_col', bcr_code, bcr_name, sep = ': ', remove = F)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = my_data2, 
          aes(fill = new_col)) + 
  geom_sf_label(data = my_data2, 
                aes(label = bcr_code))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>